# convert columns to financial accounting format worksheet conditional formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like below:

```
A       B              C          
SDF     899501607.2   -26152567.7
ISB     464284188.7   -20278910.23
ADF     0                         
SDF     3978706912   -57575106    
All     5342492708   -104006583.9
```

Using worksheet conditional formatting I want to shows the numbers in the below format(rounding, commas, negative as (), $)

```
A       B                 C        
SDF     $ 899,501,607     $(26,152,568) 
ISB     $ 464,284,189     $(20,278,910) 
ADF     $ 0               $0           
SDF     $ 3,978,706,912   $(57,575,106)
All     $ 5,342,492,708   $(104,006,584)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
import io

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO('''\
A       B              C          
SDF     899501607.2   -26152567.7
ISB     464284188.7   -20278910.23
ADF     0                         
SDF     3978706912   -57575106    
All     5342492708   -104006583.9'''), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Then you can use `pd.ExcelWriter` and [reference the documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html) to get

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output_file_name.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)'})


worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format1)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 18, format2)
writer.save()
```

which would result in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you asked about *conditional formatting* but maybe you could consider using a [custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5) like this one:

`$#,##0;[Red]$(#,##0)`

Which gives:

[image: Custom format sample]

To create a custom format, right-click on the cells, choose `Format cells...` and type the rule:

[image: Custom format setting]